# how to use an unordered_set as a hash key - ordering-invariant hash and equal_to function

Tags: c++, unordered-map, unordered-set, c++23

I am trying to use an `unordered_set` as a key to an `unordered_map`. I created `std::hash` which will iterate over the elements and combine hash of all the elements and `std::equal_to` which will iterate over the elements and do equality comparison.

But I am running into this issue: [Is iteration order of two unordered_set-s with same contents guaranteed to be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68851481)

Since the order of two sets with same contents is not guaranteed to be the same my `hash` and `equal_to` functions are incorrect.

Is there a way to make this work in C++23?

How to create ordering-invariant hash and `equal_to` function for `unordered_set`?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/344902). Why do you need an `unordered_map` of `unordered_set`? What is the purpose?

Comment: `unordered_set` already has `operator==`. For hashing see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54546), or if you want a very simple solution, combine the element hashes with something associative and commutative, such as `+` or `^`.

Comment: Why was this closed? Sane hashing of `unordered_set` isn't obvious. I don't understand what kind of debugging details we expect here, you don't need any code to explain this problem.

Comment: @JanSchultke the key/name of an object is a set of attributes, not all objects will have same number of attributes and  order does not matter, a set is desired here as the key.